# Update column in oracle in vectorized way

Tags: oracle

I have the following table:

```
Year Month Day TIME_ID

2018  12  29  (null)

2017  12  21  (null)

...   ...  ...  ...
```

I want to fill in the column `TIME_ID` in the following way: `select Year||Month||Day from Table`.

But I tried the following update statement update TABLE set TIME_ID = (select Year||Month||Day from Table) but it doesn't work because, as I understood, this operation is not vectorized.

Queistion: how can I fill in the TIME_ID column efficiently?

Comment: What does it mean, "is not vectorized"? What result do you expect? Query you wrote seems to be OK (if the result should be a *string*; otherwise, TO_DATE should be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I fill in the TIME_ID column efficiently?

Use a `DATE` data type:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET time_id = TO_DATE(
                TO_CHAR( year, '0000' )
                  || TO_CHAR( month, '00' )
                  || TO_CHAR( day, '00' ),
                'YYYYMMDD'
              );
```

If you really want it to be efficient then just store the `time_id` column as a `DATE` data type and derive the `year`, `month` and `day` columns from that as virtual columns rather than the other way around:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  time_id DATE,
  year    NUMBER(4,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM time_id ) ),
  month   NUMBER(2,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( EXTRACT( MONTH FROM time_id ) ),
  day     NUMBER(2,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( EXTRACT( DAY   FROM time_id ) )
);
```

That way you cannot insert an invalid date such as `2018-02-31` and the `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY` columns will always accurately reflect the value in the `TIME_ID` column.

Inserting your sample data:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( time_id )
  SELECT DATE '2018-12-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-12-21' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

```
TIME_ID    | YEAR | MONTH | DAY
:--------- | ---: | ----: | --:
2018-12-29 | 2018 |    12 |  29
2017-12-21 | 2017 |    12 |  21
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=817e4acd9c7912b91e6ca6bae3758cb1)*

---

If you must use a numbers for `year`, `month` and `day` then for the `time_id` column then, again, use a virtual column:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name2 (
  year    NUMBER(4,0),
  month   NUMBER(2,0),
  day     NUMBER(2,0),
  time__id DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    TO_DATE(
      TO_CHAR( year, '0000' )
        || TO_CHAR( month, '00' )
        || TO_CHAR( day, '00' ),
      'YYYYMMDD'
    )
  )
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fbf682913b74de0127483fa6ce21147d)*

Answer (score 1):

Just use this, in case your `time_id`'s type is `VARCHAR2` or `NUMBER`

```
UPDATE table_name
SET time_id = year || month || day;
```

If your `time_id` column is of type `DATE` then use `TO_DATE` function instead.